# Make a python for loop return a List of intergers

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python for loop like this

```
for i in view_overall_isp_ratings:
        #the int and the round is just for casting the values returned
        me = (int(round(i.avg_of_ratings)))
        print(me)

and this prints intergers like this 1
                                    1
                                    1
                                    1
                                    4
```

**What i want**

```
for it to produce a list like this 
    [ 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,4]
```

tried playing around with the [] but the least i could get was

```
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [4]
```

Can anyone assist

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list (outside the loop!) and append to it in each loop iteration:

```
lst = []
for i in view_overall_isp_ratings:
    #the int and the round is just for casting the values returned
    lst.append(int(round(i.avg_of_ratings)))

print(lst)
```

Or, in a much cleaner fashion, you could use a list comprehension:

```
print([int(round(i.avg_of_ratings)) for i in view_overall_isp_ratings])
```

Comment: you have saved a soul ,this definitely works , i think i now need to embrace the more pythonic way of thinking....